# When I increase the frame thickness the signallers disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib

After I increase the frame thickness in the following way

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure('Figure',figsize=(20,20))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(7)

X=np.linspace(0.,10.,100)
Y=np.linspace(0.,10.,100)
ax.plot(X,X,linewidth=6)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=70,pad=30)
plt.show()
```

You can see that in the plot it is not possible anymore to see the signallers on the frames indicating where each value is precisely. 
How can I choose the dimension of the signallers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make the ticks wider and longer by setting the `tick_params()`

```py
ax.tick_params('both', length=20, width=7)
```

[image: the plot with the wider ticks]